# transforming xml by xsl with namespace

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, namespaces, xml-namespaces

I use IE 11 and firefox for testing

the following runs fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="LEDES21Basic.xslt" type="text/xsl"?>
<ledesxml>
  <firm>
      <lf_vendor_id>GB 12 345 6789</lf_vendor_id>
      <lf_id>FR12-3456789</lf_id>
      <lf_name>Alpha &amp; Beta, LLC</lf_name>
</firm>
</ledesxml>
```

with the following stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:t="http://www.ledes.org/ledes2000.xsd"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Acounting document</title>            
            </head>
          <body>        
              <p>BODY</p>
              <xsl:value-of select="/ledesxml/firm/lf_name"/>
          </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but, my real xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="LEDES21Basic.xslt" type="text/xsl"?>
<ledesxml xmlns="http://www.ledes.org/ledes2000.xsd">
  <firm>
    <lf_vendor_id>GB 12 345 6789</lf_vendor_id>
    <lf_id>FR12-3456789</lf_id>
    <lf_name>Alpha &amp; Beta, LLC</lf_name>
  </firm>
</ledesxml>
```

You note the namespace. the preceding stylesheet fails to transform the xml.
I try two things : changing my xpath expression, use the xpath-default-namespace attribute:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:t="http://www.ledes.org/ledes2000.xsd"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="t:/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Acounting document</title>            
            </head>
          <body>        
              <p>BODY</p>
              <xsl:value-of select="t:/ledesxml/firm/lf_name"/>
          </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

both of them fail.
Firefox says: xpath expression analysis failure.

==== next try ========================================================

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:t="http://www.ledes.org/ledes2000.xsd"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Acounting document</title>            
            </head>
          <body>        
              <p>BODY</p>
              <xsl:value-of select="/t:ledesxml/t:firm/t:lf_name"/>
          </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

no more xpath error but no the expected result: lf_name is not transformed.

What can I do to transform my xml file without removing the namespace ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xpath-default-namespace` only works with XSLT 2.0 processors like Saxon 9, Saxon CE, XmlPrime, Altova, browsers only support XSLT 1.0. As for using a prefix, yes, that is the right approach, but the proper syntax is to prefix any element name, as in `<xsl:value-of select="/t:ledesxml/t:firm/t:lf_name"/>`. And leave `match="/"` as it is, a prefix is only used in qualified names.

Comment: no more xpath error (thank you), but still not display. The resulting transformation only comprises <p>BODY</p>

Comment: Is the namespace in the input XML really like `xmlns="http://www.ledes.org/ledes2000.xsd>"`? In that case of course the XSLT also needs `xmlns:t="http://www.ledes.org/ledes2000.xsd>"`.

Comment: yes, both files have `<ledesxml xmlns="http://www.ledes.org/ledes2000.xsd>">` or`xmlns:t="http://www.ledes.org/ledes2000.xsd"`

Comment: @tschmit007, try with <xsl:value-of select="//*:lf_name"/>.

Comment: I see my error by posting a copy to you, there is a `>` that should not be here.

Comment: @RudramuniTP `*:localname` requires XPath 2.0, we've established that this is a 1.0 question.

Comment: @IanRoberts, sorry for my comment.